# Setting density-specific drawables as button background

Tags: android-layout, android

I have a few buttons in my application that don't have any text, only background drawable. I need to make it so that the drawable is taken from an appropriate `drawable-?dpi` folder, and then displayed without resizing. The first part works, the appropriate image file is selected. However, it is still resized no matter what `layout_height` and `layout_width` attributes the button has. My question is: how to defeat this, and make drawables map to screen pixel-to-pixel?

The only way I can make it not to resize is to specify width and height in `px`, which is exactly what I don't want to do. And the reason I don't want to do it is `dimensions` files, in which I could have specified `px` drawable size for different densities, are differentiated by screen size, and not by density.

Here's what my layout looks like:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/btn" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did you try setting `layout_height` and `layout_width` to `wrap_content`?

Comment: @Nachi: yes indeed, it's the value I want to make the whole thing to work with. So that I don't need to make several layouts, just place correct images into correct density-specific folders. No luck, the image is scaled.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use exact image sizes from the dpi folders, you can use wrap_content for both layout_height and layout_width. It will take up the exact size as the image was defined to be.

This usually is not recommended since there are many different phones with different density, resolution and such.

Another way to use non-text images is use [nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) to make it stretch to whatever you need it to be.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. `wrap_content` still results in a scaled image. Updating the question with excerpt from my layout in case I'm doing something stupid there.

Comment: And I really don't want to make 9-patches out of every of my drawables. It seems unnecessary for my task.

Comment: Doubt it will make a difference but try ImageButton with src as your drawable.

Comment: play around with the scaletype to see if you can get things right.

Comment: Tried that, too. Imagebutton, height and width `wrap_content`, drawable as `src`, tried all the `scaleType` options. Same, it always scaled the image.